# I can't have autocomplete on types automatically generated by Prisma

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm doing a project with Next and Prisma. In my `schema.prisma`, I have several models. For example, the one below:

```
model Barbershop {
  id       String    @id @default(uuid())
  name     String
  address  String
  imageUrl String
  bookings Booking[]
  services Service[]
}
```

It turns out that when trying to use the types automatically generated by Prisma, I don't have auto-completion of my models' attributes.

I've already tried restarting VS Code and also using the `npx prisma generate` command. Did not work.

I expected that, in the code below, I would have the Barbershop type autocomplete. For example, when using the barbershop prop, the .name should autocomplete, but this does not happen, although the code works.

```
import { Card, CardContent } from "@/app/_components/ui/card";
import { Barbershop } from "@prisma/client";

interface BarbershopItemProps {
  barbershop: Barbershop;
}

const BarbershopItem = ({ barbershop }: BarbershopItemProps) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent className="p-0">{barbershop.name}</CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default BarbershopItem;
```

Another odd behaviour is that in my `page.tsx` I have the following code:

```
<div className="flex flex-wrap gap-4 px-5">
          {barbershops.map((barbershop) => (
            <BarbershopItem key={barbershop.id} barbershop={barbershop} />
          ))}
        </div>
```

I get an error saying:

```
Parameter 'barbershop' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

Edit: None of the types generated by the models have autocomplete. I tried on others and also got the same problem.

Comment: if you hover over or click into Barbershop type what does it say?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It says "(alias) type Barbershop = $Result.DefaultSelection<Prisma.$BarbershopPayload<$Extensions.DefaultArgs>>
import Barbershop"

Comment: prisma migrate dev --name 'change-name'

have you ran this since making changed on your schema?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I'm taking the same course as you (thanks Felipe Rocha • tipsparadevs) I found the solution that worked for me.

▶︎ Go to your `"tsconfig.json"` file.
Yours will probably have one like this:

`"moduleResolution": "Bundler"`

change `"Bundler"` to `"node"` like this:

`"moduleResolution": "node"`

And done i fixed it on mine.
If you have any further questions, call us on discord: tuxiiez